# ItemView has no method 'render'

Tags: marionette

I've just updated backbone.marionette from 0.9.3 to v1.0.0-beta4 and the following code is breaking:

```
PlansApp.CompositeView  = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
PlansApp.ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemVie

PlansApp.Plans.PlansList = do ({PlansApp, Backbone} = window) ->
  PlansList = {}

  PlansListItemView = PlansApp.ItemView.extend
    initialize: ->
      @bindTo this.model, "change", this.modelChanged

    modelChanged: (model, value)->
      this.render()
      this.$el.effect("highlight", {}, 6000)
      window.addTeachMeHandlers() if model.get 'IsFirst
```

It is specifically breaking on this.render() with the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'render'

This code previously used to work before the upgrade.

From looking at the source, ItemView still has a render method, so I am guessing the context is wrong or maybe bindTo has changed.

I upgraded underscore also to 1.4.1 from 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in one of the previous versions, I had to change how the EventBinder was attached to the view in order to avoid a conflict w/ the Backbone.StickIt plugin. This change means the default context of the event bindings is no longer the view, and you'll have to specify the 4th parameter - the context - when calling `bindTo`. It works the same as Backbone's `on` method:

`@bindTo this.model, "change", this.modelChanged, this`